# Circular tree with heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, heatmap, ggtree

This question is quite trivial but I cannot be handled nicely with.

I'm trying to plot a circular tree with a side heatmap.

I'm using `ggtree` but any approach `ggplo2` based is welcome.
The problems that I'm not understanding well the `gheatmap` function.

I want:
1- names AFTER the heatmap
2- 2 text columns after heatmap (for while may have the same value, but I need to know how to add it )
3- heatmap columns name nicely handled, should we remove the columns name and use different colors scales for each? wherever the solution falls might  better than the way it is now

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtree)
library(treeio)
library(tidytree)

beast_file <- system.file("examples/MCC_FluA_H3.tree", package="ggtree")
beast_tree <- read.beast(beast_file)

genotype_file <- system.file("examples/Genotype.txt", package="ggtree")
genotype <- read.table(genotype_file, sep="\t", stringsAsFactor=F)
colnames(genotype) <- sub("\\.$", "", colnames(genotype))
p <- ggtree(beast_tree, mrsd="2013-01-01",layout = "fan", open.angle = -270) + 
  geom_treescale(x=2008, y=1, offset=2) + 
  geom_tiplab(size=2)

gheatmap(p, genotype, offset=5, width=0.5, font.size=3, 
         colnames_angle=-45, hjust=0) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("HuH3N2", "pdm", "trig"), 
                    values=c("steelblue", "firebrick", "darkgreen"), name="genotype")
```

[image: This is the result I had with this code]

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I found a better way to plot the name of heatmap columns.
Also, I found that the simplification of the data was useful to
clean up a little the tip labels.
Now, I just need to add two text columns after heatmap.

```
p <- ggtree(beast_tree)  
gheatmap(
  p, genotype, colnames=TRUE, 
  colnames_angle=90,
  colnames_offset_y = 5,
  colnames_position = "top", 
) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("HuH3N2", "pdm", "trig"), 
                    values=c("steelblue", "firebrick", "darkgreen"), name="genotype")
```

[image]

UPDATE 2:

A very bad improvement
I just used ggplot to create the label and merge with `patchwork`

```
library(patchwork)

p$data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(1, y= y, label = label )) +
  geom_text(size=2) +
  xlim(NA, 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) -> adText

pp + adText
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer according [@xiangpin at GitHub](https://github.com/YuLab-SMU/ggtree/issues/330#issuecomment-664790738).

Big offset value to `geom_tiplabel`:

```
p <- ggtree(beast_tree)  
p1 <- gheatmap(
         p, genotype, colnames=TRUE, 
         colnames_angle=-45,
         colnames_offset_y = 5,
         colnames_position = "bottom",
         width=0.3,
         hjust=0, font.size=2) +
         scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("HuH3N2", "pdm", "trig"), 
                    values=c("steelblue", "firebrick", "darkgreen"), name="genotype") +
         geom_tiplab(align = TRUE, linesize=0, offset = 7, size=2) +
         xlim_tree(xlim=c(0, 36)) +
         scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, NA))
p1
```

[image: Solution 1]

Using `ggtreeExtra`:

```
library(ggtreeExtra)
library(ggtree)
library(treeio)
library(ggplot2)

beast_file <- system.file("examples/MCC_FluA_H3.tree", package="ggtree")
genotype_file <- system.file("examples/Genotype.txt", package="ggtree")

tree <- read.beast(beast_file)
genotype <- read.table(genotype_file, sep="\t")

colnames(genotype) <- sub("\\.$", "", colnames(genotype))
genotype$ID <- row.names(genotype)

dat <- reshape2::melt(genotype, id.vars="ID", variable.name = "type", value.name="genotype", factorsAsStrings=FALSE)
dat$genotype <- unlist(lapply(as.vector(dat$genotype),function(x)ifelse(nchar(x)==0,NA,x)))

p <- ggtree(tree) + geom_treescale()

p2 <- p + geom_fruit(data=dat,
                     geom=geom_tile,
                     mapping=aes(y=ID, x=type, fill=genotype),
                     color="white") +
          scale_fill_manual(values=c("steelblue", "firebrick", "darkgreen"),
                            na.translate=FALSE) +
          geom_axis_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, size=1.5) +
          geom_tiplab(align = TRUE, linesize=0, offset = 6, size=2) +
          xlim_tree(xlim=c(0, 36)) +
          scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, NA))
p2
```

[image: Solution 2]